# Validating Dynamic Rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, dynamic, data-annotations

I have built a web application for data input (the type of data is unimportant). One portion of this site allows the user to dynamically add rows of data. For the static input fields, I use DataAnnotations so that I can manage validation of the fields. When I attempt to do a similar thing for the dynamic fields, validation does not appear to work.

Here is the (general) setup of my application.

```
[Data Input Page] -> [Partial Page for Dynamic Table] -> [Table is made up of individual rows (partial page)]
```

Each page is strongly typed.

Here is an example of an individual row, partial page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Models.Person>" %>

<tr>
<% using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("People")) { %>
    <td class="ui-widget-content"><%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) %></td>
    <td class="ui-widget-content"><%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age) %></td>
    <td class="ui-widget-content"><%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber) %>  

    // [Cut] Some other, unimportant information here which allows a new row to be added.
</tr>

// This portion is not working - it does work with static fields.
<div class="validation">
    <div><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)%></div>
    <div><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)%></div>
    <div><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)%></div>
</div>
```

Any insight into getting validation to work with DataAnnotations (so it is the same/similar to what I'm already doing) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve Sanderson [blogged about validation](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) in this case.

Comment: Thanks (and accepted). That does answer the question. Crazy hack-ish, though.